# draw half line between two nodes tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have the following graph:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
]
  \node (n1) at (0,0)  [draw=black,auto=left,circle,thick,fill=red!50,scale=1.3] {$\mathbf{X}_1$};
  \node (n2) at (2,2)  [draw=black,auto=left,circle,thick,fill=red!50,scale=1.3] {$\mathbf{X}_2$};
  \node (n3) at (4,4)  [draw=black,auto=left,circle,thick,fill=red!50,scale=1.3] {$\mathbf{X}_3$};  

  \node (n4) at (3,0)  [draw=black,auto=left,circle,thick,fill=red!50,scale=1.3] {$\mathbf{X}_4$};
  \node (n5) at (5,2)  [draw=black,auto=left,circle,thick,fill=red!50,scale=1.3] {$\mathbf{X}_5$};
  \node (n6) at (7,4)  [draw=black,auto=left,circle,thick,fill=red!50,scale=1.3] {$\mathbf{X}_6$};  

  \node (n7) at (6,0)  [draw=black,auto=left,circle,thick,fill=red!50,scale=1.3] {$\mathbf{X}_7$};
  \node (n8) at (8,2)  [draw=black,auto=left,circle,thick,fill=red!50,scale=1.3] {$\mathbf{X}_8$};
  \node (n9) at (10,4) [draw=black,auto=left,circle,thick,fill=red!50,scale=1.3] {$\mathbf{X}_9$}; 

  \node (n11) at (0,5)  [draw=black,auto=left,circle,thick,fill=green!50,scale=1.2] {$\mathbf{Y}_{10}$};
  \node (n22) at (2,7)  [draw=black,auto=left,circle,thick,fill=green!50,scale=1.2] {$\mathbf{Y}_{11}$};
  \node (n33) at (4,9)  [draw=black,auto=left,circle,thick,fill=green!50,scale=1.2] {$\mathbf{Y}_{12}$};

  \node (n44) at (3,5)  [draw=black,auto=left,circle,thick,fill=green!50,scale=1.2] {$\mathbf{Y}_{13}$};
  \node (n55) at (5,7)  [draw=black,auto=left,circle,thick,fill=green!50,scale=1.2] {$\mathbf{Y}_{14}$};
  \node (n66) at (7,9)  [draw=black,auto=left,circle,thick,fill=green!50,scale=1.2] {$\mathbf{Y}_{15}$}; 

  \node (n77) at (6,5)  [draw=black,auto=left,circle,thick,fill=green!50,scale=1.2] {$\mathbf{Y}_{16}$};
  \node (n88) at (8,7)  [draw=black,auto=left,circle,thick,fill=green!50,scale=1.2] {$\mathbf{Y}_{17}$};
  \node (n99) at (10,9) [draw=black,auto=left,circle,thick,fill=green!50,scale=1.2] {$\mathbf{Y}_{18}$};  

  \node (n7h) at (9,0)  [] {$ $};
  \node (n8h) at (11,2) [] {$ $};
  \node (n9h) at (13,4) [] {$ $}; 

  \node (n1l) at (-3,0) [] {$ $};
  \node (n2l) at (-1,2) [] {$ $};
  \node (n3l) at (1,4)  [] {$ $};  

  \node (n1f) at (-2,-2) [] {$ $};
  \node (n4f) at (1,-2)  [] {$ $};
  \node (n7f) at (4,-2)  [] {$ $};  

  \node (n3t) at (6,6)  [] {$ $};
  \node (n6t) at (9,6)  [] {$ $};\draw ($(n1)!1cm!(n1l)$) -- ($(n1)!3cm!(n1l)$);
  \node (n9t) at (12,6) [] {$ $};

  \foreach \from/\to in {n11/n1,n22/n2,n33/n3,n44/n4,n55/n5,n66/n6,n77/n7,n88/n8,n99/n9}[ultra thin] \draw (\from) -- (\to);        
  \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n2,n2/n3,n4/n5,n5/n6,n7/n8,n8/n9} \draw[ultra thick] (\from) -- (\to);            
  \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n4,n4/n7,n2/n5,n5/n8,n3/n6,n6/n9} \draw[ultra thick] (\from) -- (\to);    
  \foreach \from/\to in {n7/n7h,n8/n8h,n9/n9h} \draw (\from)[dashed] -- (\to);     
  \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n1l,n2/n2l,n3/n3l} \draw (\from)[dashed] -- (\to); 
  \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n1f,n4/n4f,n7/n7f} \draw (\from)[dashed] -- (\to);  
  \foreach \from/\to in {n3/n3t,n6/n6t,n9/n9t} \draw (\from)[dashed] -- (\to);   
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like to draw a half dash line, for example between nodes X_1 and Y_{13}. How can I do this?

Comment: `\draw[dashed] (n1)--(n44);`

Comment: How half dashed line looks? Is half solid and another half dashed?

Comment: You also need `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` to use `\draw ($(n1)!1cm!(n1l)$) -- ($(n1)!3cm!(n1l)$);` By the way, why using it?

Answer (score 7):

Another interpretation of "half dashed":

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\tikzset{draw half paths/.style 2 args={%
  decoration={show path construction,
    lineto code={
      \draw [#1] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- 
         ($(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!0.5!(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$);
      \draw [#2] ($(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!0.5!(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$)
        -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
    }
  }, decorate
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, draw}, >=stealth]
\foreach \i in {1,...,5}
  \node (n-\i) at (72*\i:2) {\i};

\path [draw half paths={solid}{dashed}]  (n-1) -- (n-3);
\path [draw half paths={dotted}{dashed}] (n-2) -- (n-4);
\path [draw half paths={blue, thin}{red, very thick}] (n-3) -- (n-5);
\path [draw half paths={dashed}{draw=none}] (n-4) -- (n-1);
\path [draw half paths={dotted, ->}{draw=none}] (n-5) -- (n-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very sure, what you mind with "half dashed line" ... if it is composed from two lines, one solid and one (on small distance from solid) dashed, see, if this is solve your problem:

```
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
% half dashed line
\draw (n1) -- (n13);
\draw[dashed] ($(n1)!2pt!90:(n13)$) edge ($(n13)!2pt!-90:(n1)$);
\end{scope}
```

This addition gives:

[image]

This picture I generated with MWE, which is, hm,  very different from yours ...

```
\documentclass[border=3mm, tikz, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds,scopes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
XYnode/.style = {circle, draw=black, thick, fill=#1!50,
                minimum size=1em, font=\Large},
                    ]
% red nodes
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,3}
\foreach \y in {1,2,...,3}
{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\i}{\y + (\x-1)*3};
\node[XYnode=red] (n\i) at ({3*(\x+\y-2)-\y},2*\y-2) {$\mathbf{X}_{\i}$};
}
%green nodes
    \begin{scope}[yshift=50mm]
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,3}
\foreach \y in {1,2,...,3}
{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\i}{\y + (\x-1)*3 + 9};
\node[XYnode=green] (n\i) at ({3*(\x+\y-2)-\y},2*\y-2) {$\mathbf{Y}_{\!\!\i}$};
}
    \end{scope}
% background lines 
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
% grid below red nodes
    \draw[ultra thick]  (n1) -- (n3) (n4) -- (n6) (n7) -- (n9)
                        (n1) -- (n7) (n2) -- (n8) (n3) -- (n9);
% half dashed line
\draw (n1) -- (n13);
\draw[dashed] ($(n1)!2pt!90:(n13)$) -- ($(n13)!2pt!-90:(n1)$);
\end{scope}
% links between red and green nodes
\foreach \j [count=\jj from 10] in {1,...,9}
    \draw (n\j) -- (n\jj);
% dashed lines
\foreach \k [count=\kk from 7] in {1,...,3}
    \draw[dashed] (n\k) -- + (-33mm,0mm) (n\kk) -- + (33mm,0mm);
\foreach \k [evaluate=\k as \kk using int(\k + 2)] in {1,4,...,7}
    \draw[dashed] (n\k)  -- + (-18mm,-18mm)
                  (n\kk) -- + ( 22mm, 22mm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```